Measure area of polygon inside your area of interest AND update Attributes Table in QGIS
I've hit a wall trying to truncate WBD polygon areas inside my area of interest for the determination of that area, and having that measurement amended in the Attributes Table.
I cannot use the manual advanced digitizing tool regardless of new project, multiple projection changes at project and file levels.
This is a screenshot of

NLCD filtered for grasslands (raster);
WBD shapefiles of sub basins; and
The shapefile of Montana state boundary.

I can measure the pixels of the grasslands per sub basin, but I cannot get QGIS to update Attributes Table of WBD polygon areas inside Montana (the edges) via clipping and various other functions I've tried.


If you want to use a Processing Tool, you will find that Overlap Analysis will get the result you want. However, if your layers are in EPSG:4326 (like your project is), calculating the area in degrees is meaningless and you will need to consider reprojecting them to a local coordinate system.
Alternatively, you can use an expression in the Field Calculator on your WBD layer. No need create extra layers if you don't specifically need to.
The expression assumes that both layers are in the same projected coordinate system. You can either reproject your layers, as mentioned above, or adapt the expression to include the transform() function.
area(
    intersection(
        @geometry, 
        aggregate(        -- the aggregate function is to access the geometry of the AOI layer                 
            'AOI',        -- the name (or ID) of your AOI layer
            'collect',
            @geometry     -- the geometry of the AOI
        )
    )
)


The selected rows are to show the intersected area is the full area of the polygon if it is completely within the Area of Interest.

Thanks Matt, you're probably answering my next question. Never a dull moment.
